# Any alternatives to aspnet-request:serverVariable when using NLog with .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, nlog

As stated on the [NLog GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetRequest-layout-renderer) the  `${aspnet-request:serverVariable=String}` layout renderer is not supported in .Net Core.
The documentation doesn't provide alternatives to many of the variables available under serverVariable.

My question is, are there any alternatives? Like to access remote address, server name, port etc? Or do I just have to write a bunch of custom layout renderers [documented here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer) and dependency inject all the stuff by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ASP.NET Core there as many new layout renders. The reason is that the API  of ASP.NET Core is very different and the server variables can't be read like in ASP.NET (so non-core)

There are currently 13 layout renders for ASP.NET Core that renders a part of the request.

- ${aspnet-request} - ASP.NET Request variable.
- ${aspnet-request-contenttype} - ASP.NET Content-Type header (Ex. application/json)
- ${aspnet-request-cookie} - ASP.NET Request cookie content.
- ${aspnet-request-form} - ASP.NET Request form content.
- ${aspnet-request-headers} - ASP.NET Header key/value pairs.
- ${aspnet-request-host} - ASP.NET Request host
- ${aspnet-request-ip} - Client IP.
- ${aspnet-request-method} - ASP.NET Request method (GET, POST etc).
- ${aspnet-request-posted-body} - ASP.NET posted body / payload
- ${aspnet-request-querystring} - ASP.NET Request querystring.
- ${aspnet-request-referrer} - ASP.NET Request referrer.
- ${aspnet-request-url} - ASP.NET Request URL.
- ${aspnet-request-useragent} - ASP.NET Request useragent.

See also https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=package:nlog.web.aspnetcore

If you need something else, you could indeed create a custom renderer. If you need the http request you could use:

```cs
AspNetLayoutRendererBase.Register("aspnet-request-myrenderer", (logevent, httpcontext, config) => ... );
```

You need to reference the NLog.Web.AspNetCore package for that.

Comment: Marking your answer, because with .Net 5 in the final stretches, there are still no alternatives to this, so likely never will be either. So if you miss anything, you have to create a custom renderer and retrieve the info in your app yourself.